# tkinter, método set no asigna valores de texto a un StringVar, variable vacía

Tags: python, tkinter, método

El problema es que estoy asignando una función a diferentes botones de un formulario mediante functools subclase partial para agregar valores de texto a un StringVar y cuando imprimo estos valores en el shell obtengo solo la palabra PY_VAR4 y no los valores {si, no, si, no...} que he agregado en la variable de control. He leído al respecto y sé que el parámetro de la función es None como los valores del StringVar

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import os.path
import json
import sqlite3
import mysql.connector
from functools import partial
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from sqlalchemy import values
from typing import Optional
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from pathlib import Path
from sqlalchemy import values

class Cuestionario_Uno(tk.Frame):
    
    #list1= []
    #num = len(list1)
    #a = 0

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        
        #variable StringVar usada para asignarle valores de cadena con functools.partial
        self.valores_respuestas= tk.StringVar(value="")

        self.lbl_encabezado = tk.Label(self, text="Alexis Barrios Expert System Forms", fg="white", bg="darkgray", font=("Open Sans", 10), padx=10, pady=10)
        self.lbl_encabezado.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky='w')
        self.lbl_p1 = tk.Label(self, text="Fatiga?:", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_uno = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_uno.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_dos = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_dos.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lbl_p2 = tk.Label(self, text="Aumento de peso?:", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_tres = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_tres.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_cuatro = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_cuatro.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lbl_p3 = tk.Label(self, text="Pérdida de peso?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_cinco = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_cinco.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_seis = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_seis.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        
        
        self.lbl_p4 = tk.Label(self, text="Rostro hinchado?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_siete = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_siete.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_ocho = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_ocho.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lbl_p5 = tk.Label(self, text="Problemas para tolerar el frío?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p5.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_nueve = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_nueve.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_diez = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_diez.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lbl_p6 = tk.Label(self, text="Problemas para tolerar el calor?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p6.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_once = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_once.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_doce = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_doce.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lbl_p7 = tk.Label(self, text="Dolor articular?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p7.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_trece = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_trece.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_catorce = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_catorce.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.lbl_p8 = tk.Label(self, text="Debilidad muscular?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p8.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_quince = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_quince.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_dieciseis = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_dieciseis.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.lbl_p9 = tk.Label(self, text="Piel seca?", font=('Open Sans', 10), bd=10)
        self.lbl_p9.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.btn_diecisiete = tk.Button(self, text="SI", command=partial(self.responder, "si,"))
        self.btn_diecisiete.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn_dieciocho = tk.Button(self, text="NO", command=partial(self.responder, "no,"))
        self.btn_dieciocho.grid(row=9, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.lista_de_respuestas = []
        self.btn_add = tk.Button(self, text="Continuar y guardar", font=('Open Sans', 10), bg="#009ACD", command=self.build_cuestionario_dos_listarr)
        self.btn_add.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        

    def responder(self, respuesta):
        self.aux= self.valores_respuestas.get()
        self.concatenado= self.aux + str(respuesta)
        self.valores_respuestas.set(self.concatenado)
        print(self.valores_respuestas)
        
    # Obtener la lista completa de respuestas de las preguntas.
    varres= self.valores_respuestas.get()
    print(varres)

    def build_cuestionario_dos_listarr(self):
    
        print("Iniciar el cuestionario 2")
        root5 = tk.Toplevel()    
        buildApp = Cuestionario_Dos(master=root5)
```

Necesito las respuestas para enviarlas a un algoritmo de sistemas expertos en python para producir un diagnóstico

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una consulta, como seria posible publicar mi pregunta en inglés? La verdad es mucho más fácil obtener una respuesta fiable

Comment: Hola AlexisSpace.BO, es fácil, abres [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) enlace y haces tu pregunta...

Comment: No se que quiere decir una respuesta fiable... aca hay grandes conocedores de python.. pero te alcanza con hacerla en el sitio en ingles....